# How to disable an array of dates from html 5 datepicker using angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, datepicker

Need some help here. I have a datepicker in html5 native code. 
Code looks like this

```
    <input name="cidt" type="date" id="cidate" ng-model="reserve.ci" min="{{today}}" required ng-change="getMinCo()" disableDates>
```

And the directive

```
    myapp.directive('disableDates', function(){
        return function(scope, element, attrs){
            var disableddates = ["2016-07-14","2016-07-15"];
            //need to code here
        }
    });
```

note: angularjs uses **jqlite** to modify attributes of an element. But there is no reference I could find to change the specific dates of this input type, other than min and max.

I just need to figure out how to disable those dates from being selected. Couldn't find any resource on google either. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no property or method provided as far as i have seen in w3c input type = date for disabling certain dates but you can only enable valid dates and that also according to the range.

Below is the link:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#date-state-(type=date)